# OrientDB Query Product with their last comment

Tags: orientdb

I have two vertex classes: Product, Comment. Each Product can have many comments. Comments have two properties:  date and message.

{Product}-->{Comments}

I need to write a query that retrieves all products with their last comment message.

`Product   Message                   Date
A         the last comment          01/01/2016
B         xxx                       22/01/2011
...`

I couldn't find any documentation on this sort of query.

Comment: You have some edges that link the products with the comments, or you are using a Linklist?
What version of OrientDb ara you using ?

Comment: I'm using edge to links product to comments, and this is version 2.1.11 community

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a small db test

```
create class Product extends V
create property Product.name String

create class Comments extends V
create property Comments.message String
create property Comments.date DATE

create class Product_Comments extends E

insert into Product(name) values ("Product 1")   // 12:0
insert into Product(name) values ("Product 2")   // 12:1

insert into comments(message,date) values ("message 1","2016-01-01")  //13:0
insert into comments(message,date) values ("message 2","2016-02-01")  //13:1

insert into comments(message,date) values ("message 3","2016-01-15")  //13:2
insert into comments(message,date) values ("message 4","2016-02-14")  //13:3


create edge Product_Comments from 12:0 to 13:0
create edge Product_Comments from 12:0 to 13:1
create edge Product_Comments from 12:1 to 13:2
create edge Product_Comments from 12:1 to 13:3
```

[image]

You can use this query

```
SELECT name, $checks[0].date as date , $checks[0].message as message FROM Product 
let $a = ( select expand(out("Product_Comments")) from $parent.$current),
$checks= ( select date, message from $a where date in ( select max(date) from $a))
```

[image]

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an Edge connecting Product and Comment and you always insert chronologically you can do:

```
SELECT Name, last(out()).Message, last(out()).Date FROM Product
```